# Transparent Grid in Windows Phone?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to write a page for WP8 which plays video, using the MediaElement API.
I am having difficulties in placing the play/pause controls over the video.

I am currently using a grid to house the controls over the video. The problem is that I cannot make the grid transparent. This is the XAML -

```
<StackPanel Background="Transparent">

    <MediaElement Name="media" Source="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" AutoPlay="True" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <!-- Play button. -->

        <!-- Pause button. -->
        <Grid  Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="85" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets\transport.pause.png" Height="79" Width="79"/>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Assets\transport.play.png" Height="79" Width="79"/>

        </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I can still see a black portion where the Grid is.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I've also dealt with this issue and ended up setting the opacity of the Grid to .5 or so. IMO this is better than having a completely transparent background anyway because certain video content can render your controls "invisible". Imagine very dark video content w/dark controls or bright white video content w/white controls.

Comment: I've added a new answer which is the correct answer and provides a simple working example. Summary: you used the wrong layout controls.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've dealt with this issue before but can't remember exactly how I solved it. I remember researching [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is using visual media as a `Brush` to then paint the background of the `Grid` that houses the buttons. IIRC, the issue is not necessarily with the `Grid`, it's with anything overlaying the `MediaElement`. Because of some special drawing procedure involved with the `MediaElement` it doesn't handle overlays and transparencies well. There is a solution, but like I said I can't completely remember. But try out using the video as a `Brush` for the background of the `Grid`.

Comment: I tried using a VideoBrush as the background for the containing Stackpanel, and although it looks fine, the video does not play very smoothly. What could be happening?

Comment: It worked well on the device, but stutters on the emulator. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why the downvote? Especially if this is the accepted answer? The reason it stutters is because the the emulator is pretty slow; I've had similar issues with a lot of animations, not just videos, using the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You've put the controls in a `StackPanel`. That means that you'll end up with:

```
StackPanel
    MediaElement
    Grid
       Button/Image 
       Button/Image
```

A `StackPanel` is designed to stack controls either horizontally or vertically. It is not for overlaying controls. So, the black background you're seeing is the background beneath the `Grid`, which is likely the default background brush/color of the application (black).

[image: Showing the problem]

If you instead were to use a `Grid` to host the controls, you can use an overlay as you need to:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" >
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Name="media" Source="Assets/sample_mpeg4.mp4" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <Grid  Background="#80000000" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" >Pause</Button>                   
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click_1" >Play</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

It's now:

```
 Grid
    MediaElement
    Grid
       Button
       Button
```

It would look something like this:

[image: Improved]

Using the `Grid`, I've put both the `MediaElement` and the inner `Grid` in the same cell (by using the default attached property values for `Row` and `Column` which are `0').

In the above code, I've used a `Grid` to layout the `MediaElement` and another `Grid` which will layout the two `Button`s I've used. In this case, I've centered the `Grid` with the `Buttons` so that the buttons appear in the center of the `MediaElement`.

I've also used a somewhat transparent `Background` for the `Grid` which contains the buttons.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It was because you used a StackPanel instead of a Grid.

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt work for me. Have you tried it with an actual video?

Comment: To clarify: I am using a grid now for the layout, but the transparency was fixed by using the videobrush, not the fact that I used a Grid and not a stackpanel.